# Can gmail (smtp.gmail.com) post incoming mails to my application instead of my applications pulls the mail?

Tags: gmail, sendmail, sendgrid

I am using smtp.gmail.com to send mails.
I want to read/parse mails in my application.

I know how to pull the mails, there are API libraries to handle that. It is bit over do for my application.

Instead, is there any way gmail can post mails to my application like sendgrid does ?

Comment: Could you mention programming language you use and meaning of "like sendgrid does"?

Comment: Programming language is doesn't matter i think. 
"like sendgrid does": Sendgrid provides the webhook, if sendgrid gets mail, it post that mail in http which should point to our app, so that our application will get the mail as http post request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get emails from a gmail account, and want a webhook to do such, you could use [Context.io](http://context.io)'s [Webhook Feature](http://context.io/docs/2.0/accounts/webhooks).

However, at the maximum volume you'll be able to send out with Gmail, I'd recommend looking toward an email service provider's free plan. If you're familiar with SendGrid already [SendGrid's Free Plan](http://sendgrid.com/user/signup) will give you access to both low volume sending, and the Parse webhook. Other email service providers will give you the same functionality on their free plans, as well (e.g. [Mailgun](http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#routes)).

**Disclaimer**: I am a SendGrid employee.

Comment: I expected the webhook feature in gmail itself. Now i am choosing the services like cloudmailin, Mailgun and Context.io. Looks like mailgun is cheaper more free option.

Comment: Unfortunately, gmail does not have that kind of functionality (as far as I've seen).